# Unable to download a csv file in node js using express js

Tags: node.js, csv, express, download

I am using `Json2csv` for converting JSON to CSV  and I am successful in converting the JSON in CSV file but now I want to make a file called `output.csv` of that data and I want as soon as that API is clicked `output.csv` file automatically downloads.

Here is what I have tried

```
const JsonToCsv = (fields,res,data) => {


  const opts = { fields };
  try {
    const parser = new Json2csvParser(opts);
    const csv = parser.parse(data);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    // const csv = parser.parse(myData);
    fs.writeFile('./output.csv', csv, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log('wrote output.csv');
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.csv');
        res.download('./output.csv');
        res.send(csv);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Now the csv file is made but it is not downloading.

Comment: is it logging any errors?

Comment: @vibhor1997a I have updated my question in that error is there please have a look

Comment: does `console.log(csv)` logs the csv?

Comment: @vibhor1997a yes it logs the csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this with `fs.readFile` and not with streams as I see you are using the synchronous API from the `json2csv` module.

You can do as follows for forcing download the csv file.

```
const csv = parser.parse(myData);
  fs.writeFile('./output.csv',csv, (err) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
      else {
          console.log('wrote output.csv');
          res.download('./output.csv');
      }
  });
```

Comment: thanks @vibhor1997a  now file is made but it is not starting download

Comment: It should download, please update your post with the latest code you tried for your route.

Comment: What error are you having now? Try removing `res.send(csv)`